# Set up Xorg with two monitors at different resolutions

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, resolution, xorg, xorg.conf

I'm trying to set up Archlinux on WMware to have with two monitors at different resolutions. This is my xorg.conf file

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "Mac"
        Option "PreferredMode" "800x600"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "HP"
        Option "LeftOf" "Mac"
        Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "Device0"
        Option "Virtual1" "HP"
        Option "Virtual2" "Mac"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Personalizzato"
        Monitor "HP"
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth 24
        EndSubSection
        Device "Device0"
EndSection
```

The problem is that the monitor marked as "HP" works well and if I change the resolution on the file, the resolution is actually changed. Instead, the monitor marked as "Mac" doesn't change its resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the question.
The Monitor Section regarding "Mac" was ignored because the association in Device section is

```
Option "*Monitor*-outputname" "MonitorIdentification"
```

and not

```
Option "Outputname" "MonitorIdentification"
```